# Activity timeline to display date time instead of date for a call

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, system-admin

Is it possible to configure the past activity look in the timeline for calls?

I am trying to display the actual datetime of a logged call, but it only shows the date, in comparison to an email sent, where it actually displays the datetime.

Is there any set up that I need to change to display this information?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now, it is not possible to configure it through Out of the box functionality.

An idea has been created for the same, You can upvote it.

Idea Description:- The Activity Date field is of type date/time yet we cannot set the time component of the field in the GUI.

- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000J5ojAAC

What Salesforce documentation says:-

**Date (ActivityDate) -**

Indicates one of the following:

- For a task, the due date of a task
- For an event, indicates the start date of the event only if
  IsAllDayEvent is set to true

> This field has a time stamp that is always set to midnight in the
>   Universal Time Coordinated (UTC) time zone. The timestamp is not
>   relevant; do not attempt to alter it in order to accommodate time zone
>   differences.

**In addition**:

Due Time (ActivityDateTime) For an event only, if IsAllDayEvent is set to False, contains the concerned time.
For more info on Date/Due Time and it's relation with Start Date,  [SOAP API Developer Guide: Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm)

Reference:- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000180843&type=1

Hope it helps you.